# How to access all sub-directories of a website without links?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am scraping a website which has links in the format: `site.net/user/username/post`

For most users, I can simply go to `/user/username` and extract links to all their posts and iterate. However, for some users, the site /user/username is apparantly broken and is empty. However, Google can still find the posts under /user/username/post, and the posts are intact.

Is there a way for me to get a list of all `/user/username/post1|post2|post3 --> [post1,post2,post3]` or just straight access them?

Comment: read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can't. The HTTP protocol doesn't provide any way to list directories.

Comment: Google must have found them from links on other sites, or links between pages on the site.